# What is the algorithm where you rotate around a board in a clockwise pattern?

Tags: algorithms

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I have no clue what I'm trying to achieve is called and couldn't find anything helpful.

I'm trying to find the name of an algorithm that starts at a point and rotates around a "board" in either clockwise or anti-clockwise rotation.

I'll draw some examples to shown what I'm trying to get because I can't really word what I'm after.
[image: algorithm]
The algorithm starts at 1 and moves around in a clockwise rotation moving around the radius from the centre. The algorithm count resets when it goes another layer out.
Each number is how many steps of the algorithm it takes to get to this square.

Comment: I am not sure there is a name for this, this is just index manipulation.

Comment: I don't think that there is a name, as this is routine work. If you are after an implementation, better ask for it (but not in this site).

Answer (score 0):

From the starting point $(k,\frac{n-1}2)$, go up $k$ times, right $2k$ times, down $2k$ times and up $k-1$ times.